# Is there a way to show custom calculated delivery dates in Shopify?

Tags: reactjs, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api, shopify-storefront-api

I have a Shopify store and I would like to, on the shipping page in the checkout, show delivery dates under shipping methods.
To calculate the delivery dates I need item's SKUs in the cart, the shipping address, the store name (because I have multiple stores actually) and the shipping methods "DeliveryMethodDefinition" IDs.

I tried to retrieve the data in a checkout extension ui app, I can get the store name directly by using "shop" from useApi and the items skus by using query, but impossible to get "DeliveryMethodDefinition" ids and shipping address. Is there a way to get the cart id in the shipping page so I could make a call to a personal api to calculate it and send it back to make the checkout extension UI to show it?

And I am not talking about the checkoutToken as it is deprecated in the order resource.

I also searched in the docs to try something else, found something called carrier service but couldn't use it. I am not even sure if it was the thing I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Shopify API version 2024-01 :

You can set delivery dates only for shipping rates that are provided by a `carrier_service` resource created by your app.

It others terms, you can't set delivery dates for shipping rates that are :

- created manually in Shopify admin
- provided by another app

Note :
if you want to implement a `carrier_service` thing, you may want to check how the delivery dates are displayed in the checkout process. You may have unexpected results when your minimum and maximum delivery dates include non-working days.

Comment: It is pretty easy to not include non-business days in Custom Carrier Service responses. Almost all Date/Time libraries provide a snippet or method that does just that. I wrote custom delivery date Apps for at least 20 merchants back in the heyday of needing Apps for this... and that was indeed an important aspect.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, now I understand, I was trying to use carrier service with a shipping rate made manually in the admin. another question is there someway to change the "order processing time" by service?